# HTML- Header for Dynamic Table

Tags: javascript, html, json

This is my current table-

```
txt += "<table border='2'>";




     for (x in myObj) {
txt += "<tr>"
txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].friend_id + "</td>";
txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].birth_date + "</td>";
txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].first_name + "</td>";
txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].last_name + "</td>";
txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].gender + "</td>";
txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].phone+ "</td>";
txt += "</tr>"
```

I'm populating it with JSON output, which works fine. However, I don't know how to add the header to the table. I tried adding the header out of the for loop, but it wouldn't align with the table in the loop. How do I connect both?

Current table- https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VxyU.jpg

Comment: They should be "connected" if you have the same number of th/thead elements as you do tr td elements (outside of the for loop).  Check this link for examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: These are static tables though- Mine is dynamic. I get how to add headers in static tables, but in dynamic, if I have it in the for loop, won't the headers get constantly repeated in the table? @Rob Wilson

Comment: Not if they are outside the loop - they will only be output once

Comment: "I tried adding the header out of the for loop," .... show us how you tried this. Better still, provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txt += "<table border='2'>";
txt += "<tr>"
    txt += "<th>Friend Id</th>";
    txt += "<th>Birth Date</th>";
    txt += "<th>First Name</th>";
    txt += "<th>Last Name</th>";
    txt += "<th>Gender</th>";
    txt += "<th>Phone</th>";
txt += "</tr>"



 for (x in myObj) {
    txt += "<tr>"
    txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].friend_id + "</td>";
    txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].birth_date + "</td>";
    txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].first_name + "</td>";
    txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].last_name + "</td>";
    txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].gender + "</td>";
    txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].phone+ "</td>";
    txt += "</tr>"
}
```

Comment: A good table should also have a [`thead` and `tbody`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Advanced#Adding_structure_with_%3Cthead%3E_%3Ctfoot%3E_and_%3Ctbody%3E) ... `txt += "<thead><tr>"` ...then after the `th` lines... `txt += "</tr></thead><tbody>"`